# How can I stop iterating "n" before the end of a map when the iterators aren't random-access?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I would like to traverse a map in C++ with iterators but not all the way to the end.
The problem is that even if we can do basic operations with iterators, we cannot add or compare iterators with integers.
How can I write the following instructions? (`final` is a map; `window`, an integer)

```
for (it=final.begin(); it!=final.end()-window; it++)
```

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: @user<unnamed>: you should avoid the function call in the condition part of the `for` loop, as it will be executed at each round. This is premature pessimization :)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot subtract from a map iterator directly, because it is an expensive operation (in practice doing --iter the required number of times). If you really want to do it anyway, you can use the standard library function 'advance'.

```
map<...>::iterator end = final.end();
std::advance(end, -window);
```

That will give you the end of your window.

Comment: And obviously, you'd compute this once *before* entering the loop. No sense computing it at each iteration :)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::map<T1, T2>::iterator it = final.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < final.size()-window; ++i, ++it)
{
  // TODO: add your normal loop body
}
```

Replace `T1` and `T2` with the actual types of the keys and values of the map.

Comment: I'd make the loop's increment instruction be `++i, ++it` so they both always happen together. In the current code, a `continue` statement will ruin everything.

Comment: True. I tried to keep it easy by doing it at the end of the loop, but `continue` is a good reason not to put it there.

Comment: @6502: No, if you have `window < final.size()`, you had another problem, namely how-the-hell-the-program-arrive-here-in-a-state-that-invalid-state; using signed type merely hides the problem in a way that happens to be acceptable in the current situation.

Comment: This code when `window > final.size()` will do bad things instead of simply not iterating at all. It's another case that shows how bad was the idea of choosing an unsigned type (i.e. a "modulo 1<<n integer") as container size in the standard library. More correct code here is to test `i + window < final.size()` instead – 6502

Comment: @Lie: it was a typo. The problem is when `window` is **greater** that `final.size()` and `final.size()-window` becomes a huge positive number.

Comment: also, wrap the entire code body here in `{}` to keep `it` only in the scope of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make 'it' an iterator as well ?

See the example here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
size_t count=final.size();
size_t processCount=(window<count?count-window:0);
for (it=final.begin(); processCount && it!=final.end(); ++it, --processCount)
{
  // loop body
}
```

This one is a bit safer:

- It takes care of the case when your map is actually smaller than the value of `window`.
- It will process at most `processCount` elements, even if you change the size of your map inside your loop (e.g. add new elements)
- According to STL, `size()` can take O(n) time to compute, although usual implementations can do this in O(1). To be on the safe side, it is better not to call size() many times, if it is not necessary.
- 'end()' on the other hand has amortized constant time, so it should be OK to have it in the for-loop condition
- `++it` may be faster than `it++`. The post-increment operator creates a temporary object, while the other - does not. When the variable is a simple integral type, compiler can optimise it out, but with iterators it is not always the case.